# Retry caso dê Timeout com Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Eae galera, estou com um probleminha para dar um retry em um POST usando axios caso exceda do Timeout. Estou tentando implementar essa(https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry) biblioteca junto ao axios, mas não funciona. Vamos ao código:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const convert = require('xml-js')
const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry');


const CLIENT = axios.create();
CLIENT.defaults.timeout = 1000
axiosRetry(CLIENT, {
    retryCondition: (error) => {
        return axiosRetry.isNetworkOrIdempotentRequestError(error) || error.code === 'ECONNABORTED';
    }
});

class Consult {
    constructor(username, password) {
        this.username = username
        this.password = password
    }    

    async getResponse() {
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
            }
        };
        const xml = 'string_conection'

        return await CLIENT.post('url', xml, config)
        .then(response => {
            const result = convert.xml2json(response.data, {
                compact: true,
                spaces: 4
            })
            return result
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.code);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Consult
```

Quem poder dar um help eu agraço :)

Answer (score 5):

Eu criei minha própria função para `retry`:

```
const axios = require('axios');

/**
 * Waits a determined time to fulfill a Promise
 *
 * @param {number} ms - The milliseconds to fulfill the Promise
 *
 * @returns {Promise<any>} Represents the fulfilled time
 */
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

/**
 * Try to request the following URL using the maximumRetry option
 *
 * @param {string} url - The URL to connect
 * @param {object} options - The options to pass to axios
 * @param {number} attempt - The current attempt number
 * @param {number} delay - The time in milliseconds to wait before request
 *
 * @returns {Promise<*|void>} Represents the fulfilled request
 *
 * @private
 */
const retry = async (url, options, maximumRetry = 0, attempt = 0, delay = 0) => {
  try {
    await sleep(delay);
    const { data } = await axios.request({ url, ...options });

    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    if (attempt >= maximumRetry) throw e;

    return retry(url, options, attempt + 1, (delay || 1000) * 2);
  }
};
```

E a utilização se dá da seguinte forma para 3 tentativas, por exemplo:

```
const response = await retry(url, {
  data,
  headers,
  httpsAgent,
  method: 'POST',
  timeout: opts.timeout,
}, 3);
```

Comment: Hmm, boa. É, acabou que ontem eu também criei minha própria função. Não sei se posso postar ela aqui como resposta para ajudar a galera...

Comment: @Develop_SP pode sim, só é importante você aceitar alguma resposta como escolhida pra que a pergunta fique no fluxo normal, mesmo que seja a sua própria

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode interceptar *request* do *axios* sempre que houver erro e caso o *Http Status Code* seja de *timeout* (408) voce tenta novamente.

Segue implementação do [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Exemplo:

```js
        axios.onError((res) => {
            if (res.response.status === 408) {
                console.info(`Tentar novamente`, res.config)
                return axios.request(res.config)
            }
        }),
```